# Unable to turn on wifi in Ubuntu 12.04 live boot

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-12.04, livecd, backtrack

Actually this is kind of weird but I tried running backtrack r3 and Ubuntu 12.04 live on my laptop but both the times I was not able to switch on my Wireless using the toggle switch, in fact normally in windows it turns on a led on my laptop when wireless is on. But in ubuntu and backtrack this led never glows.

I tried running rfkill list

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

But still It is not able to detect my home network and not even the led glows.

Details about the wireless card.

```
# lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Broadcom Corporation
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f1900000-f1907fff

# iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Might help if we knew the wireless card in question.

Comment: thanks for response. it is dell wireless 1704 802.11 b/g/n (2.4GHz) as appear in windows device manager. please tell me if any other info needed

Comment: Ca you find out the chipset? It should be listed if you run `lspci` from the linux live session.

Comment: Here is what it shows
`$ lspci | grep Network`

`02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)`